# Placing Text-Container over Image using php Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to program a plugin that sets a Text-Container over a Image in Wordpress. Im using the Divi Themen. My idea: I need to find where Images are rendered and add my container where I place my text with something like "get_meta_data()". The needed field are already in the media library. I just need to find how to create the conainer and place it over every image where my text exists. Any Ideas/Tipps?

Comment: I recommend that you do some research and make some attempts. We'll be glad to help if you run into some specific issue with your existing code along the way. Currently, this question is too unspecific and broad for SO.

Comment: I would use the image as a background of a div which contains said text ....